# Step 3 of Angular.js tutorial

Tags: angularjs

I am on step 3 of the angular tutorial.  I've gotten everything to work before step 3.  However, on step 3, when I run ./scripts/e2e-test.sh, I get the following error:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError**: *describe* is not defined

I believe it is referring to scenarios.js.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download Setp-3 source code,and compare different with your code? [like this](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/compare/step-2...step-3)

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to do that as I have followed the instructions in the tutorial and it does not seem to be doing as it is suppose to as stated in the tutorial.

Comment: Maybe tutorial has mistake(this is not the first time),compare it,or show your code.